# Regain space from VirtualBox partition

Tags: virtualbox

I had VirtualBox create some partitions. Now I would like to get that space back, how can I do so?

I thought that right-clicking and selecting "Remove" would be sufficient, but the space allocated to the drives has not been restored. Any ideas?

Comment: VirtualBox does not support shrinking the size of a virtual HDD.  Are you trying to shrink the size of the file itself or shrink the size of the virtual hdd?  There is a huge difference between the two tasks.

Comment: Not sure what the proper terminology is, but I used VirtualBox to install Ubuntu 17 (allocated 50GB for this task) and a copy of Windows 10 (again 50GB). I have since removed both virtual drives but for whatever reason, my HDD is still missing 100GB, as if the two drives were still there...

Comment: Then you didn’t delete the actual virtual HDD files.  You need to do that simply deleting the virtual machine might not be enough

Comment: Where can I find these files?

Comment: The VBox online manual documents the default location

Comment: The only information I was able to find on the online documentation that is related to uninstallation pertains to uninstalling the VirtualBox program itself, and not any residual files that are left over after removing virtual drives.

Comment: It's going to be in a folder created by VirtualBox contained within user's documents directory on Windows.  The manual indicates what that directory is.

Comment: Ahh, I found the folder-- but the only files it contains are for one VM--the one that I am currently using-- the other two that I removed are not there. The space for the VD seems to be contained within a ".vdi" file--but unfortunately, after doing a search on my PC, I only found one .vdi, and it is within the aforementioned folder.

Comment: Use WinDirStat as an Administrator to find the files